# What is the meaning of int (*pt)[5] in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I Have read some where about this type declaration.
Declaration is:

```
int (*arr)[5];
```

i'm little bit confused with this type declaration.Actually what is the meaning of this declaration and when do we use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int *arr[5]
```

`arr` is array of 5 pointers

```
int (*arr)[5]
```

`arr` is a pointer to an array of 5 integer elements

Check the code below:

```
int a[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5};
int (*arr)[5] = &a;
printf("%d",(*arr)[2]);
```

Now the array element can be accessed like

`(*arr)[i]` not `*arr[i]`

Answer (score 2):

It means `arr` is a pointer to an array of 5 integers.  Compare with the less-confusing array of five pointers:

```
int* arr[5];
```

That's why you need the parentheses.

Comment: > when do we use it
Whenever we need it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

According to the “declaration follows use” rule:

- `(*arr)[i]` is an `int`, where `i <= 5`, therefore
- `*arr` is an `int[5]`, an array of five integers, therefore
- `arr` is an `int (*)[5]`, a pointer to an array of five integers.