# What does "int *[5]" indicate in c?

Tags: c, pointers

I was going through study materials from my previous year at University, and I saw a question like:

What is the difference between `int *a` and `int a[5]` and `int *[5]`. What does the last one indicate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27811025/what-is-the-meaning-of-int-pt5-in-c check the last  answer of the link

Comment: Questions like this are really not welcome here, because they practically shout: “I didn’t do any research of my own! Spoon-feed me the answers!” Please read the help files about how to ask good questions.

Comment: http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28*arr%29[5]

Comment: Did you perhaps instead of `int *[5]` meant `int *a[5]`?

Answer (score 0):

the `int *a[5]` declares an array of pointers to int.

the easiest was to determine the specifics of a variable declaration is read it from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell:

- `int *a` - creates a pointer to an `int`. This should contain the memory address of another `int`.

  Example values of `*a` are `0x00001`, `0x000057`, etc.
- `int a[5]` - creates an array that contains five `int` elements with each element containing an `int` values.

  Here's a visualization of the possible values of each element in the array:

  ```
  -------------------------
  | Array element | Value |
  -------------------------
  | a[0]          |     1 |
  | a[1]          |     2 |
  | a[2]          |     3 |
  | a[3]          |     4 |
  | a[4]          |     5 |
  -------------------------
  ```
- `int *a[5]` - creates an array that contains five pointer to an `int` elements which each element containing the memory address of another `int`.

  Here's a visualization of the possible values of each element in the pointer array:

  ```
  -------------------------
  | Array element | Value |
  -------------------------
  | a[0]          | 0x000 |
  | a[1]          | 0x001 |
  | a[2]          | 0x002 |
  | a[3]          | 0x003 |
  | a[4]          | 0x004 |
  -------------------------
  ```